# PHP MYSQL - Function + HTML Article

Tags: php, html, mysql

HTTP ERROR 500
Can't open page....

Hello i can't load page with my actual index.php (with achievements)
Code:

```
 <?php

 ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
 include '../endecrypt.php';
 require '../connect.php';

 dbc();
 $id = decryptCookie($_COOKIE['uid']);

 if (isset($id)) {

   $u_data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE     user_id = '".$id."' "));

    $silver = $u_data["silver"];
    $grzyby = $u_data["mushroom"];
    $nick = $u_data['user_name'];
    $lvl = $u_data['lvl']; 
 ?>

 <?php } 
 if($u_data['os1'] == 0){ $stringz = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os2'] == 0){ $stringz2 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz2 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os3'] == 0){ $stringz3 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz3 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os4'] == 0){ $stringz4 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz4 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os5'] == 0){ $stringz5 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz5 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os6'] == 0){ $stringz6 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz6 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os7'] == 0){ $stringz7 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz7 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os8'] == 0){ $stringz8 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz8 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os9'] == 0){ $stringz9 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz9 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os10'] == 0){ $stringz10 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz10 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os11'] == 0){ $stringz11 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz11 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }
 if($u_data['os12'] == 0){ $stringz12 = "<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>"; } else{ $stringz12 = "<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>"; }

  function os($u_data){ ?>  

    <article class="col-1-3">
        <div class="wrap">
                <center><img src="images/os.png" /> <img src="images/grzyb.png" />
                <font color="white">+ 10</font></center>
                <br>
                <center><a class="button" href="go.php?typ=os&item=1"><?php"" . $stringz3 . ""?></a></center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="content">
                          <br><font color="white" size="5">Osiągnięcie 10 lvl<br></font>
                          <font color="white" size="2">Dodaje 10 grzybów</font>
                </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="col-1-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                    <center><img src="images/zpet.png" /> <img src="images/grzyb.png" /><font color="white">+ 15</font></center>
                    <br>
                    <center><a class="button" href="go.php?typ=os&item=2"><?php"" . $stringz2 . ""?></a></center>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="content">
                                    <br><font color="white" size="5">Posiadaj Gryfosmoka = Smokogryfa!<br></font>
                                    <font color="white" size="2">Dodaje 15 grzybów</font>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </article>
```

Here i cut 10 articles...

How to replace that ifs? Maybe short version?

```
    <article class="col-1-3">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <center><img src="images/zgold.png" /> <img src="images/grzyb.png" /><font color="white">+ 750</font></center>
                    <br>
                    <center><a class="button" href="go.php?typ=os&item=12"><?php"" . $stringz12 . ""?></a></center>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="content">
                                    <br><font color="white" size="5">Kup złotą ramke (Bogactwo Skurwysyny)<br></font>
                                    <font color="white" size="2">Dodaje 750 grzybów</font>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </article>  
<?php
        }
?>
```

I don't know what is a problem :/

Och god text is too short and i cant psot that problem on stackoverflow damn ...

Comment: Error??? Getting errors??

Comment: Chk error log and also chk the file or folder permission. Permission must be 755

Comment: `HTTP ERROR 500`
Cant open page :/

in another file i have `if ($u_data['vip_time'] >= 1) { $info = "" . number_format($vip, 0, "." , ".") . " <font color='white'>dni</font>";

                        } else {

                        $info = "<font color='red'>Brak!</font>";
                        }`  with print_f `<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vip: <font color=\"#FFFF33\">" . ($info) . "</font></b>` and it work good

permission 644, no needed 755 :)

Comment: this ist false: `<?php"" . $stringz3 . ""?>`  php interpret this as `<?php""` not as `<?php` !! write this `<?=$stringz3?>` or `<?php echo $stringsz3; ?>`

Comment: Add code in your question not in comments. Missing semi colon in this line `$info = "<font color='red'>Brak!</font>"`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php } function os($u_data){ ?>    
<?php
 if($u_data['os1'] == 0){ 
$stringz = '<font color="red">Odebrano!</font>'; 
} 
else
{ 
$stringz = '<font color="green">Odbierz!</font>'; 
} ?>

    <article class="col-1-3">
        <div class="wrap">
                <center><img src="images/os.png" /> <img src="images/grzyb.png" />
                <font color="white">+ 10</font></center>
                <br>
                <center><a class="button" href="go.php?typ=os&item=1"><?=$stringz?></a></center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="content">
                          <br><font color="white" size="5">Osiągnięcie 10 lvl<br></font>
                          <font color="white" size="2">Dodaje 10 grzybów</font>
                </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Now work :) thanks